# Una sola palabra para un hablante no nativo de un idioma

Tags: solicitud-de-término

La pregunta es sencilla: busco una palabra que describe una persona que ha aprendido y habla una lengua *extranjera*. Solo hay sustantivos para locutores nativos, por ejemplo *hispanohablante*. Puedo describir una persona así, pero busco una sola palabra.

Comment: En inglés se suele llamarles ["L2 speakers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_language).

Comment: @ukemi - También he visto "Limited English Person (LEP)."

Answer (score 4):

En principio, *hispanohablante* no tiene por qué significar un hablante nativo.  Pero tampoco te da forma de distinguir entre un nativo y alguien que lo tiene como segundo (o tercero, etcétera, idioma)

Si no hay problema que la palabra sea génerica para todos los idiomas, tienes **neohablante**.  Si quieres decir *hispanohablante no nativo* no creo que puedas en una palabra, solo puedes cambiar el enfoque entre *neohablante del castellano* o *hispanohablante no nativo*.